# How can i get the red green and blue values from an rgb/rgba string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

If I have the string `rgba(111,222,333,0.5)` how can i extract the individual colours from the string, i.e.

```
red => 111
green => 222
blue => 333
opacity => 0.5
```

I would like to be able to use a neat clean solution for this so I am assuming a regular expression would be best?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd avoid regex for a predictable string, and suggest:

```js
// assigning the rgb() colour to a variable:
var colorString = "rgba(111,222,333,0.5)",

    // using String.prototype.substring() to retrieve
    // the substring between the indices of the opening
    // and closing parentheses:
    colorsOnly = colorString.substring(
        // here we find the index of the opening
        // parenthesis, and add 1 to that index
        // so that the substring starts after that
        // parenthesis:
        colorString.indexOf('(') + 1,

        // and terminating the substring at the
        // index of the closing parenthesis:
        colorString.lastIndexOf(')')
      // here we split that substring on occurrence
      // of a comma followed by zero or more white-
      // space characters:
      ).split(/,\s*/),

    // String.prototype.split() returns an Array,
    // here we assign those Array-elements to the
    // various colour-, or opacity-, variables:
    red = colorsOnly[0],
    green = colorsOnly[1],
    blue = colorsOnly[2],
    opacity = colorsOnly[3];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PN4pe/).

Or, given that you want an object returned:

```js
var colorString = "rgba(111,222,333,0.5)",
  colorsOnly = colorString.substring(colorString.indexOf('(') + 1, colorString.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
  // here we initialise an empty Object:
  components = {};
// here we assign the Array-elements to the
// named properties of that Object:
components.red = colorsOnly[0];
components.green = colorsOnly[1];
components.blue = colorsOnly[2];
components.opacity = colorsOnly[3];

console.log(colorsOnly, components);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PN4pe/1/).

Edited to use more contemporary JavaScript:

```js
const colorString = "rgba(111,222,333,0.5)",
  // here we use destructuring assignment to assign the returned Array-elements
  // - in respective order - to the named variables:
  [red, green, blue, opacity] = colorString.substring(colorString.indexOf('(') + 1, colorString.lastIndexOf(')')).split(/,\s*/),
  // passing the variables into the Object Literal; in this instance
  // we're passing in the variables which are the literal name of the
  // properties they define and which also contain the relevant value:
  colorObject = {
    red,
    green,
    blue,
    opacity
  };
console.log(red, green, blue, opacity, colorObject);
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: Just out of curiousity, I'm interested in the reason why you suggest this - is regex significantly more resource intense, or is it just slower?

Comment: regex can be quite expensive in terms of processing and matching the various expressions. It's not *always* slower, it's just that simple string, or array, functions tend to be a little cheaper. I haven't performed any comparison to determine the faster solution to this question, but I prefer to avoid regex where possible, if a more 'simple' approach can be used instead. So...personal bias, and (typically) expensive regex lead me to recommend this alternative.

Comment: So I got curious about this in this application so I did a comparison between my regex solution I'm using, chaining split commands, and your solution mentioned here.

Results for 100,000 elements were: Regex:76ms Split:121ms subString: 96ms  -- results stayed similar across multiple runs.   So in this case regex is faster but not by too much.

Answer (score 3):

The Regex for this would be:

```
^rgba\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)\)$
```

Javascript code:

```
var regex = /^rgba\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)\)$/g; 
var input = "rgba(111,222,333,0.5)"; 
if(regex.test(input)) {
  var matches = input.match(regex);
  for(var match in matches) {
    alert(matches[match]);
  } 
} else {
  alert("No matches found!");
}
```

You may want to trim the matches and/or convert the values to numbers to get the required RGBA values in JavaScript.

Play with this at [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=827ab00e-937a-4705-8f21-0d766bd382c6)

If you wanna handle spaces between parameters in the regex itself, it may start looking ugly like this:

```
^rgba\(\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*,\s*([^,\s]+)\s*\)$
```

Answer (score 3):

making to david more simpler and expainatory

```
 var colorString = "rgba(111,222,333,0.5)";
 var colorsOnly = colorString.split(")"); //gives "rgba(111,222,333,0.5" at index 0
 var colorsOnly = colorString[0].split("(");   //gives "111,222,333,0.5 at index 1
 var colorsOnly = colorString[1].split(",");
```

gives "111" at [0], "222" at [1], "333" at [2] and "0.5" at [3] **but NOTE:** all of these have string data types as all of these are subStrings.

```
red = parseInt(colorsOnly[0]);
green = parseInt(colorsOnly[1]);
blue = parseInt(colorsOnly[2]);
opacity = parseFloat(colorsOnly[3]);
```

use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` methods to convert the strings into integer and float resp.

Comment: This won't work. 3rd and 4th line of the top code block should be var colorsOnly = colorsOnly[0].split("("); then var colorsOnly = colorsOnly[1].split(",");

Answer (score 0):

For Ahmed Bilal's answer, I have something to correct. If I am wrong, please also feel free to correct me! :)

It should be:

```
    var colorsOnly = colorString.split(")");
    var colorsOnly = colorString.split("(");
    var colorsOnly = colorsOnly[1].split(",");
```

Notice the change of the fourth sentence. Since ColosOnly from the third sentence has represented the outcomes after the "(" splitting. So I think it should be `colorsOnly[1]` in the third sentence. I tried it on myself and got proved.

Again, if I am wrong, please also feel free to correct me! :)

Comment: This doesn't work but you're on the right track. The first line doesn't do anything since it's overwritten by the 2nd without saving anything.

It's harder to read but you can just chain everything together: 
var colorsOnly = colorString.split(")")[0].split("(")[1].split(",");

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution.

```
const rgbaStrToValues = function( rgba ) {
    const realNumPattern = '([+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d+)';
    const rgbaPattern = `rgba?\\(` +
        ` *${ realNumPattern } *, *${ realNumPattern } *,` +
        ` *${ realNumPattern } *(?:, *${ realNumPattern } *)?\\)`;
    const regexp = new RegExp( rgbaPattern );
    const result = regexp.exec( rgba );
    if ( ! result ) { return; }

    const { 1: red, 2: green, 3: blue, 4: alpha } = result;
    if ( ! ( red && green && blue ) ) { return; }

    const { min, max } = Math;
    return {
        red  : max( min( Number( red ), 255 ), 0 ),
        green: max( min( Number( green ), 255 ), 0 ),
        blue : max( min( Number( blue ), 255 ), 0 ),
        alpha: alpha ? max( min( Number( alpha ), 1 ), 0 ) : 1,
    };
};

rgbaStrToValues( 'rgba( 111, 222, 333, 0.5 )' );
```

I wrote the description of this code in Japanese at

- ['rgb[a](R, G, B[, A])' を正規表現で処理して、各値をメンバーとしてもつオブジェクトを返す関数。 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/juthaDDA/items/d81f45295095eb4563f4)

Answer (score -1):

if it's always in rgba format you can do something like this:

```
var str = 'rgba(111,222,333,0.5)'

var red = str.substr(5,3);
var green = str.substr(9,3);
var red = str.substr(13,3);
```

Comment: This is true, but it's perfectly valid for an `rgb()`, or `rgba()`, string to have `rgba(2, 3, 4)`, so the `substring()` approach isn't necessarily the best option (unless you're able to enforce numbers with leading-zeroes).

Comment: @DavidThomas you are right, i was just providing an alternative to the regexp.
maybe with a split well used...

Comment: This answer is just not flexible enough.